# PHP- Assigning DIV an ID from databse to display appropriate data

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

Im new to PHP and have set up a connection to my server with Queries that retrieve data from my database.

One of the Columns im getting is 'NoteID', this also has a 'NoteName' column and a 'Note' column.

I currently have it so for every row of data that is in the Notes table it pulls through as a separate DIV. If you would like to see this please see [this page](http://discovertheplanet.net/general_notes.php)

```
<!-- Main Body Area -->

<div class="main-container-notes">
    <div id="left-box">
        <?php 

        echo "<div style='width: 100%;'>";

        while( $noteName = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultNotes, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            echo "<div class='hvr-bounce-to-right1 hover-cursor' style='width: 100%; border-right: 5px solid #00AA88; height: 50px;'>" . $noteName['NoteName'] . "</div>";
        }

        echo "</div>";
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="right-box">

        <!-- This will display the Note Text in the 'Note' column -->

    </div>
</div>

<!-- End Main Body Area -->
```

**Above is the HTML/PHP**

```
$getNotes = "SELECT NoteID, NoteName, Note FROM Notes";
```

**Above being my Query**

Say on the Notes table i have the following:

NoteID |  NoteName  | Note

1      |  Test Note |   This is some text associated with that name

How do i make it so when a user clicks on '*Test Note*' it displays '*This is some text associated with that name*' in the DIV to the right of it

So i essentially need to give the DIV a '*NoteID*' of '*1*' so it can pull through the Note associated to that ID.

I hope i have explained this correctly. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You're going to need some JavaScript and maybe even some AJAX.

Comment: Ok, thought it might be a possibility, i wasn't sure if i could do something like giving each DIV and ID and the ID is set using the NoteID from the Database and then using that display a note based on the DIV id? EDIT: I suppose the AJAX would be because im getting the info from the server and displaing it without reloading the page actualy, good point

Comment: Not sure what you're saying there, but you'd still need some JS.

Comment: I edited my comment sorry, could you give me a hint as to where i would need the Javascript, sorry im not too sure on the process required to make this work

Comment: You'd need JS to handle the clicking of the ID.

Comment: Ok i will have a look and see what i can come up with, thanks for the response